# Report generating test failed

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

I've been trying to make scheduled reports with zabbix 5.4 but i keen getting the following error when i try to test:

```
Cannot fetch data: chrome failed to start:
Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported.
See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.
.
```

I don't know where my errors lay. i installed google chrome and i followed all the instruction and created /var/lib/zabbix/ also chown zabbix:zabbix /var/lib/zabbix/ chmod 755 /var/lib/zabbix
but nothing .please help me i you know my error

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to create a Zabbix user with a directory, that's why I got this kind of error.

```
addgroup --system --quiet zabbix

adduser --quiet --system --disabled-login --ingroup zabbix --home /var/lib/zabbix --no-create-home zabbix
```

Comment: So, what is the complete solution? Where/how did you create this?

Comment: nice. Weird that you had to do this since AFAIK, the user is created at install time.

Comment: yes in other installations I never had the error but maybe my installation went wrong with me noticing